# Installing IPython for Sublime Text 2's embedded Python interpreter

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext

I am trying to install the IpythonIntegration package in sublime,

I installed in a bash shell:

1. the latest ipython
2. pyzmq
3. pyside

However, the sublime console still gives me an error of

```
Reloading plugin /home/areal/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/ipython_repl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 62, in reload_plugin
  File "./ipython_repl.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.zmq.blockingkernelmanager import BlockingKernelManager
ImportError: No module named IPython.zmq.blockingkernelmanager
```

**EDIT:**
Even a `import IPython` won't work.

When in python console, `import IPython` and `import zmq` work, however:

```
from IPython.zmq.blockingkernelmanager import BlockingKernelManager
```

Fails with:

```
ImportError: No module named zmq.blockingkernelmanager
```

I have `0MQ 3.2` (also tried with 2.x), and latest `PyZMQ`.
I am working with `Python 2.7.2` on `Ubuntu 11.10`.

So in general I have 2 problems:

1. No IPython in Sublime (I assume it is because sublime works with an embedded interpreter)
2. No zmq module in IPython

Comment: I edited my question with some more details, thanks

Comment: I know that on OSX you can configure used Python interpreter, but on Linux you do not (currently) seem to have this freedom :( The would be install setuptools against the embedded Python interpreter and then use it to install the packages. Not sure if this is possible, though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not using Ubuntu, but I meet similar issue in Mac OS X.

The reason why it success in standalone python and fail in sublime text 2 is : sublime text 2 is using python 2.6 defaultly, while you standalone python is 2.7.

To solve this, in my OS X, I create a soft link from 2.7 to 2.6, something like below:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
sudo mv 2.6 2.6-backup
ln -s 2.7 2.6
```

I think you can do same thing in Ubuntu.