# Opening ipython from sublime text

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I added the following plugin to sublime text 2 which is meant to open the ipython qt console:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
from subprocess import call
# import os

class ipythonQtCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        call(["start","ipython", "qtconsole", "--pylab", "--ConsoleWidget.font_size=9", "--ConsoleWidget.font_family='Consolas'"],shell=True)
```

Initially it worked just fine, i.e. the plugin opened an ipython shell. I then added a menu item and a key binding. At some point something must have gone wrong since now I get this error when I run the plugin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 43, in <
odule>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\__init__.py", line 1
, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", lin
 31, in <module>
    from IPython.config.configurable import SingletonConfigurable
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\configurable.py", li
e 31, in <module>
    from loader import Config
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\loader.py", line 32,
in <module>
    from IPython.utils.path import filefind, get_ipython_dir
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\path.py", line 29, in
<module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\process.py", line 25,
in <module>
    from ._process_win32 import _find_cmd, system, getoutput, AvoidUNCPath, arg
split
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py", l
ne 21, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Chris\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

I tested the script by running it line by line in the st2 shell itself and it is the last line `call([...])` that causes the error. I find this a little strange since the command works ok when calling it from somewhere else, e.g. ipython itself.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717260/installing-ipython-for-sublime-text-2s-embedded-python-interpreter?rq=1) questions might be related, however I'm on Windows 7/8 and am not quite sure what the equivalent to a softlink is. I'm also using the portable st2 version (for the record... not sure if this matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict with the st2 native python. In any case I managed to get `os.system(...)` to work when changing the working directory using `os.chdir()`.